# How can I manually create a pixel perfect image sprite?

Tags: website-design, cs5, adobe-creative-suite, image-sprite

I want to use one of the Adobe Creative Suite 5 programs to create an image sprite of all the small icons and images on my webpages.

I've done it a number of times before in Photoshop but can't quite get every icon to be at the exact coordinates I intend them to be at.

The last method I used was to explicitly define the correct size of each as a shape, and use snap-to and line guides to line them all up where I want each image, and then insert the images and hide the shapes.

This takes a little while and to my dismay, there always seems to be something that's a pixel or two out of place, messing with my beautiful site designs.

**What method can I use to set up a grid of images with varying sizes to be at specific coordinates?**

**Which of the Adobe CS5 Programs has the best functionality for this?**

and a loosely relevant side question..

**For the purpose of rendering in a browser as fast as possible, should the images be lined up vertically, horizontally or in a roughly equal sided rectangle?**

Comment: Recently I've been using this: http://draeton.github.io/stitches I just like the visual aspect of it..

Answer (score 4):

> Which of the Adobe CS5 Programs has the best functionality for this?

Depends on which you are designing your sprites in. I created UI buttons in Photoshop, so that's what I used to create my sprite file. I used a `JPG` because it gave me the lowest file weight with all the different colors for my button.

> What method can I use to set up a grid of images with varying sizes to
>   be at specific coordinates?

You may be over-thinking this process. You can simply lay your graphics out however you need them and with **CSS** point to the correct sprite through the `background-scale` property. I DO however, keep buttons that are generally the same size pretty close to one another for grouping purposes.

Essentially, it's purely up to how you and the programmer work together. If you **ARE** the programmer, then align them however you see fit.

Comment: Great answer. Adding to it, I usually draw a grid with Guides, just to keep all sprites distributed regularly. This helps a lot when you have to start writing your css positions, because you know the numbers will always follow a pattern.

Comment: Your coordinates are going to vary depending on the size of the images. If your purpose for a methodical approach is to simplify the CSS coding, then you can align all your images left and create a vertical sprite image. Then your `background-scale` coordinate will start with the image width and end with zero so: `background-scale: Xpx 0px`.
OR, you can set up your images horizontally, then your `background-scale` property will start with 0, `background-scale: 0px Xpx`

Answer (score 2):

> What method can I use to set up a grid of images with varying sizes to be at specific coordinates?

Grids and Guides, that goes for Illustrator and Photoshop. Set up a grid that matches either the lagest size you'll be using or half the lagest size.

> Which of the Adobe CS5 Programs has the best functionality for this?

In theory, InDesign, as it has the best grid control. In practice, Illustrator and Photoshop, depending on where your files are.

> For the purpose of rendering in a browser as fast as possible, should
>   the images be lined up vertically, horizontally or in a roughly equal
>   sided rectangle?

As far as I know there is no advantage really. Having done a 3000px sprite before I know its convenient for the developer as the coordinates change in fixed steps. So he wouldn't even have to look at the sprite if I added an item, he just fixed the coordinates in one dimension (e.g. +32px).